# Java while loop timing

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm making a Java game and I'm stuck on how to do timing easily. I know there's the delta time thing, but that would mean that I have to insert that delta variable in almost every movement/update function?

I was wondering if I can just time the main While loop of the game so it runs/loops every 50 miliseconds, rather then as fast as it can.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the "delta time thing". You have a loop, you record start time at the beginning and end time at the end. You sleep X - (time to process all events).

Answer (score 1):

Changes in position are functions of time, so it makes sense to have to pass the time delta into most functions that update game state.  It's the natural thing to do; I wouldn't be apprehensive of doing so.

While it is possible to insert delays every frame (and you almost certainly want to do so, as there's no point in having a game run at 1000 fps), it is usually detrimental to have your update logic *assume* that each frame will have taken a preset amount of time.  Doing so results in choppiness when one frame happens to take longer than others.

To give your game a certain framerate, the general approach for each frame is as follows:

- Record the current time as `startTime`.
- Do the state updates.
- Redraw.
- Record the current time as `endTime`.
- Sleep for `(1 / framerate) - (endTime - startTime)`

Comment: Is the framerate a variable I want? and endTime-startTime will always give a positive intenger over 1 which will cause a negative sleep?

Comment: @NeHatchickVerma: The framerate is something like "60 frames per second" which when inverted is 1/60 second per frame.  If we assume the times are measured in seconds (usually it's milliseconds, but that's a simple conversion).  This *can* result in a negative value, but typically won't.  Simply don't sleep if it's a negative value.

Comment: well, end time will always be greater then start time, and if you subtract it from a number smaller then one it will always be negative.

Comment: @NeHatchickVerma: Not if your end time and start time are measured in the same units.  For example, your timing mechanism might give you a date in floating point seconds.  If it's in milliseconds, that's no problem: `1 / 60 frames per second =~ .017 seconds per frame = 17 milliseconds per frame`.  Always reconcile your units.

Comment: Oh I see now, let me try this!

Comment: The sleep function doesn't seem to work at all :/ I use Thread.sleep(1000); just to test but even that wont work. I think i'll just use the Delta method.

Comment: @NeHatchickVerma: I can't help you if all you're going to say is "it doesn't seem to work at all".  I can assure you that `Thread.sleep(1000)` works just fine; if you're having trouble with it then you'll need to give more information, example code, etc.